# Why does django date filter gives me entries from the next day as welll

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to access a database which has say two entries for 2016,9,25 and two entries for 2016,9,26, each of those entries have different time... I view them by listing each of them using the task.start_time in my template following is the list that I get

```
TASK        Task.title                  duration    start_time                  project     project_color   user
1st task    This is the first task      0:02:40     Sept. 25, 2016, 11:42 p.m.  Unassigned  NO COLOR    faizank
2nd task    This is the second task     0:01:30     Sept. 25, 2016, 11:47 p.m.  Unassigned  NO COLOR    faizank
3rd task    asdasdasdasd                0:20:00     Sept. 26, 2016, 12:19 a.m.  Unassigned  NO COLOR    faizank
3rd task    this is the problem         0:20:00     Sept. 26, 2016, 12:22 a.m.  Unassigned  NO COLOR    faizank
```

start_time is a datetime_field, now i am filtering the datetime object using the following queries

```
>>> c= Task.objects.filter(start_time__date=datetime.date(2016,9,25)
```

This gives me

```
<QuerySet [<Task: 1st task>, <Task: 2nd task>, <Task: 3rd task>, <Task: 3rd task>]>
```

but when I change the date to 26 it gives me an empty set....

I even did this

```
>>> c= Task.objects.filter(start_time__date=datetime.datetime(2016,9,25,0,0,0,0,pytz.UTC)
```

got the same result.

So why is the date returning the entries from 26 as well....and on querying 26 it returns an empty set....

EDIT 1:

So I just figured out, the dates are stored with different times, I don't know why the template does not show the actual times. So in case of the above entries I checked the actual times and found the following...

```
>>> d= <QuerySet [<Task: 1st task>, <Task: 2nd task>, <Task: 3rd task>, <Task: 3rd task>]>
>>> d[2].start_time
```

and got the following

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 25, 19, 19, 59, 477000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

which clearly shows that the 3rd task is stored at a different time and the one it is showing in the template, in fact I think it is exactly -5h from the time it is displaying which is GMT, so the real question now is why is template showing different time for the same model....and more importantly how can I correct it...

Comment: Is your [`USE_TZ`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) var set to `True`?

Comment: yes it is.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Django QuerySet reference for `date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#date):

> When `USE_TZ` is True, fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering.

Given that both the tasks occur shortly after midnight, I suspect that the conversion to your set timezone is causing the issue you are seeing.

Comment: right on my friend, so now my problem is that when I filter on the backend the times are different and when I display them in templates the times are different, how can I make them both the same...Assuming that the user would want and expect the times to be in his own timezone, so how can I filter based on what the user actually wants like how can I actually get values for the values of 26, sept....

Comment: @fazkan I think that would a great follow-up question, once you've taken a brief look through the Django docs. I don't have an answer off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an horrible workaround, but it worked for me. Disable USE_TZ and enable back again after the query is done:

```
from django.conf import settings
    settings.USE_TZ = False
    .... [query]
    settings.USE_TZ = True
```